# Type hinting and multiple constructors

Tags: php, php-7

I've been looking into the new features for PHP7 and thought I might begin to ready my project for the new features it introduces, like scalar type hinting.

One of the first problems I encountered was my constructors in various classes. I have some generic contrustors that acts something like this:

```
public function __construct($data = null) {
    if (is_numeric($data)) {
        $this->controller->createById($data);
    }
    elseif (is_array($data)) {
        $this->controller->createByArray($data);
    }
    elseif (strlen($data) > 0) {
        $this->controller->createByUrl($data);
    }
}
```

Introducing type hinting for this method will of course throw errors in all directions.

As far as I know PHP7 does not introduce support for multiple constructors. Are there any ways to get around this problem, or is this one of the limitations of the language?

Comment: Don't introduce the type hints for that method?

Comment: @N.B. Yeah, I know that is a possibility, but comming from OOP-background I'd really like my entire codebase to be truly object oriented ;)

Comment: Programming and OOP specifically are for solving problems. You have no problems that need solving via programming, you suffer from OCD and now you mistook that OCD for the language limitation. Sadly, this isn't language limitation. It's just some thorn in your side because you have some silly constructor that accepts anything and now you want to type hint via 3 constructors what the value is. Is that really "OOP"? Complex, stupid code that solves no problems?

Comment: @N.B. I beg to differ, constructor overloading is very common in typical OOP languages like Java and C++. The question was asked because I was wondering if there are some way to go past this limitation in PHP that I was not aware of, sadly it is not. OCD has nothing to do with wanting to utilize the new features of type hinting to have PHP more strictly typed.

Comment: Since I'm wondering what problem you're solving is, is there any chance you can write pseudo-php code with overloading the constructor (imagining PHP supported that) so it's clearer *how* you'd approach what you want and *what* the problem you're solving is. If I were in your shoes, I would have different ways of passing a variable of a certain type to a constructor that creates more stuff, but that's me and I could be silly, old and totally wrong. Mind sharing your idea with the rest of us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, that's one of the limitations of the language.
(and the `strlen() > 0` anyway can't be checked via a type. That auto-casts to string… so your method allows everything but "", null and false?)

Generally, there is RFCs in draft to expand the typehinting of PHP in 7.1:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types

That would allow you to write `int | float | array | string $data = null`.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid so. Thanks for linking the rfc for union types. Too bad PHP does not support multiple constructors, although it might be something coming in future versions now that it is more relevant than before. Anyways, thanks for clear answer to my question.

Comment: Function overloading (the generalized version of multiple constructors) will not really come to PHP as it's impossible to resolve conflicts, especially with weak typehinting (not strict types) [or we'd need sophisticated rules what's prioritized which will just end up confusing everyone … especially as `declare(strict_types=1)` is caller-specific … Different behavior for different typing modes? wat?!?]. That's why we're rather going the way of union types which will allow you what exactly to do.